# crypto.subtle.digest , array buffer is too large

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

If array buffer is too large such as 1.3gb , how can i do , thanks

code are here:

```
crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', new Uint8Array(["1.3gb content"],{})
```

Comment: why the empty Proxy?

Comment: sorry , the code just copy at other question, already change the code,Thanks

Comment: probably not, you can only use so much memory on a single tab, and the hash likely doubles it.

Comment: Thanks dandavis.